# Pointer in main still pointing to a variable in a function

Tags: c, pointers, scope

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void changeAddressofPtr(int ** ptr);

int main()
{
    int num = 12;
    int * numptr = &num;//num pointer points to num variable

    printf("%d\n",*numptr);   //just a check
    changeAddressofPtr(&numptr);  //send address of pointer to be able to change it
    printf("%d",*numptr);  //check value after changing

    return 0;
}

void changeAddressofPtr(int ** ptr)
{
    int newNum = 8;
    *ptr = &newNum;  //make main's pointer point to newNum
}
```

I was trying this out and expected an error or some wrong garbage value printed in the second printf() but this is the output:

```
12
8 //Value of variable I thought would be deleted
```

Comment: This just means it hasn't been overwritten yet. Don't rely on this behavior.

Comment: You're invoking *undefined behavior* - anything can happen in this code

Comment: Just because a variable goes out of scope doesn't mean the memory it occupied cease to exist.

Comment: Add another call to printf before the last one.

Comment: For the behaviour to be different, the memory would have to be actively cleared (making C programs slower than necessary), or overwritten (you were lucky).

Comment: Ahh didn't realize this is undefined behavior, I thought it would throw an error and was confused when it worked.

Comment: Before or after calling the function, and why? @CostantinoGrana

Comment: @BareWithImANoob never expect this in C ... there are no runtime errors defined. An error that doesn't violate a constraint (= is still compilable code) is always just invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Well, it is easy to bloat simple facts to pages of text, the real art is brevity here. I like the answer of "Charles Brunet" or even "msw" in the duplicate. There is a reason why there is an _upper_ instead a lower limit on for example theses. Eric Lipperts answer goes well over the target here in my eyes ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen I opened the answer you sent but just to check is c and c++ identical in this aspect?

Comment: @Ctx **most** people (obviously not the OP here) asking questions like this here didn't grasp yet what *undefined behavior* means and for those, this answer is perfect ... giving a nudge to adjust their logical thinking. But this discussion is off-topic here anyways.

Comment: @BareWithImANoob Mostly. C++ has exceptions, so there can be some "runtime errors" thrown. But those aside, programming errors lead to undefined behavior in C++ as well.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for the help and the link @FelixPalmen